# Can I use a parameter for the criterion column in a where clause

Tags: sql-server

In English:

I want to pass both the column name and criteria as parameters to a query from my application.

In SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] 
    @Col nvarchar,
    @ColValues nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM PEOPLE
    WHERE @Col IN (@ColValues)
```

SQL Server accepts this query but it does not return the correct values.  For example, if I pass @Col as "LastName" and @ColValues as "Smith, Jones" the query does not return any records even though those LastNames exist.

Is the only way to do this is to use Dynamic SQL?  I've looked at all the previous SO questions suggested but none have dealt with this specific question.

Comment: yes, only with dynamic SQL

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise you end up with a `varchar` of **exactly ONE character** in length - typically *not* what you want ....

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use Dynamic SQL?

Comment: @MatRichardson  No particular reason other than I read so many comments about the dangers of that approach although, I must say, in this particular application, the chances of that happening are about nil ... yeah, I see several people over there ROTFLTAO.

Comment: @marc_s  I just left the lengths off for simplicity.  In my actual app, all lengths are specified.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly Dynamic SQL would be more performant, and I would not recommend this on a large table.  However, it can be done without going dynamic.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Column1] varchar(50),[Column2] varchar(50),[Column3] varchar(50),[Column4] varchar(50),[Column5] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Dog',456,'Long','Short','Small')
,('Car',454,'Blue',NULL,NULL)
,('Fruit',466,'Apple','Pear',NULL)

Declare @Col varchar(50) = 'Column3'
Declare @ColValues varchar(100) = 'Blue,Apple'

Select Distinct A.*
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Field = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = QuoteName(a.value('.','varchar(max)'))
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') = @Col
             ) C
  Where charindex(C.Value,'['+replace(@ColValues,',','][')+']')>0
```

**Returns**

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
Car     454     Blue    NULL    NULL
Fruit   466     Apple   Pear    NULL
```

Comment: @Lamak Like I always tell my kids,   Always, Only, and Never are really big words :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an alernative... but it's only when the number of possible columns in the filter is fixed and small.

The basic idea is that for column values you use Table as input parameter, let's say '@ColValues'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine

Then you use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM People
WHERE 
(@ColName = 'LastName' and EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @ColValues WHERE ColValue = People.LastNAme)
OR
(@ColName = 'FirstName' and EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @ColValues WHERE ColValue = People.FirstName)
OR
(@ColName = 'FullName' and EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @ColValues WHERE ColValue = People.FullName)
OR
...
```

Also check the performance.

Comment: This approach looks promising but I'm not sure my situation fits your criteria very well.  Let me try it on some sample data to see how it goes.  I've used table-value parameters in other parts of the app so I should be able to give it a go without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these various approaches and finally decided in this case that dynamic SQL was the best approach.  Thanks for the ideas, they may come in handy elsewhere.